# ASP.NET MVC 3 indexing varchar columns

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3, optimization, dapper

I am fairly new to performance testing on SQL Server but I would like to speed up my search queries. I have a table called `locations` and it is only used for **"GET"**. I have 2 columns called `city` and `state`. Users inputs some search criteria into a textbox and then I bring back the information from that location using the following code

```
var city = textbox.city;
var state = textbox.state;
var search = sqlConnection.Query<location>("Select * from locations where city = @Ucity AND state = @Ustate", new { Ucity = city, Ustate = state }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Both columns are `Varchar(50)`, would indexing them make the queries faster? Or somehow optimizing my query. I been hearing a lot of mixed answers since these are strings.

Comment: An index *might* help - but since you're pulling back **all columns** by using `SELECT * FROM ....` that likelihood is fairly small. Unless your query criteria are extremely selective - returning less than 1-5% of the data rows - changes are good that SQL Server's query optimizer will use a table scan / clustered index scan even with an index present - since it will always have to do an expensive key lookup into the actual data to get **all columns**

Comment: How do you confuse ASP.NET with SQL Server?

Comment: I did not confuse any part, I am also looking to see if there is anyway i can optimize my search query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> would indexing them make the queries faster?

Um.... Yes? Since this is an equality match search, non-clustered indexing (presumably a single index spanning state and city in that order) would help hugely if there are a non-trivial number if rows in that table.